# Import Get Arxiv Metadata (Atom Feed) into Excel

Tags: excel, atom-feed

I am a novice when it comes to tasks like this, and am struggling to work it out.

I would like to get the results of this search on Arxiv.org into a table in excel.

http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=all:computer%20science&start=1&max_results=1000

The data is in atom feed format. I need it to be displayed in columns according to the tags shown in the feed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Not sure which version of Excel you have, for example on Excel 2016.  You can go to `Data > Get External Data > From Web` (or you can save that webpage as an `.xml` file and then use `Data > Get External Data > From Other Sources > From XML Data Import`) to import it.  And then follow the direction to import the XML file

At the end, you can get something like below for you to massage data:

[image]